# While submitting url to Google for indexing, it's showing "Downloaded HTTP response: Expires: Wed, 17 Aug 2005 00:00:00 GMT"

Tags: joomla-3.x, google

I have just upgrade my site to Joomla 3.6.2.

While submitting the url to Google for indexing, it's showing:

> Downloaded HTTP response:
>   Expires: Wed, 17 Aug 2005 00:00:00 GMT

The expiration is `2005`, how to correct it?

I have jotcache enable, but there is no browser cache enabled.

Comment: Try the "expires headers" plugin maybe? https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/expires-headers it should allow you to set your headers

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is set in your `.htaccess` file - check your `.htaccess` file for any entries that may cause this. If everything is OK with your `.htaccess` file, then try disabling `JotCache` to see if it's the one causing the problem (I highly doubt it though).

Comment: Even joomla.org has this expire header as 2005. It should not be coming from htaccess

Answer (score 1):

It is in the file:
public_html/libraries/src/Application/WebApplication.php

```
if (!$this->response->cachable)   
        {       // Expires in the past.
    $this->setHeader('Expires', 'Wed, 17 Aug 2005 00:00:00 GMT', true);

            // Always modified. 
    $this->setHeader('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT', true); 
    $this->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
```